# How to use exceptionExpression in Spring Retryable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

So I have a basic method which already has @Retryable annotation. I recently came across "exceptionExpression" to suppress retry based on some condition. I want to know what are some of the ways I can use this exceptionExpression. I have tried message.contains method. But can I use maybe a result from a boolean function to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

See the java docs:

```java
/**
 * Specify an expression to be evaluated after the
 * {@code SimpleRetryPolicy.canRetry()} returns true - can be used to conditionally
 * suppress the retry. Only invoked after an exception is thrown. The root object for
 * the evaluation is the last {@code Throwable}. Other beans in the context can be
 * referenced. For example: <pre class=code>
 *  {@code "message.contains('you can retry this')"}.
 * </pre> and <pre class=code>
 *  {@code "@someBean.shouldRetry(#root)"}.
 * </pre>
 * @return the expression.
 * @since 1.2
 */
```